# Using ag grid with vuejs, how can i make each cells reactive without resetting every cells?

Tags: vuejs3, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am facing some issues with AgGrid in Vue3 about reactivity.

I would like to make every cells reactives to other cells changes with custom inputs components (CellRenderer + CellRendererParams).

For exemple, I would like to concatenate firstname and lastname of a person. I know there is the valueFormatter property, but I don’t want to use it since each cell could be a input, even the concatenation. On top of that, i would expect that the “rowData” object I pass through props to be reactive, so when I change data in the table it should update outside and vice-versa

I made a Plunk to show you my methods : https://plnkr.co/edit/h4eIDnV9pLjqFY0L?open=main.js
Here is the main part i think. This is where i change the data of the row. And when i change that i would like for the other cell to "update" and not refresh.
`function onUpdate(value) {
// -- SET DATA VALUE --
// With this method, my main data object is updated, but not other ones and I loose focus on input
props.params.node.setDataValue(props.params.field, value.target.value);

```
  // -- SET DATA -- 
  // With this method, I should list all columns to make an update and decide which one I would like to update, and I loose focus on my input, not viable
  props.params.data.fullname = [props.params.data.firstname, props.params.data.lastname].join(" "),
  props.params.data[props.params.field] = value.target.value;
  props.params.node.setData(props.params.data);

  // The ideal solution :
  props.params.data[props.params.field] = value.target.value; // And nothing else
}`
```

When i use setData(), setDataValue() or setRowData(), it rerender the entire row or table, so I loose focus on my input, when i directly mutate the field in props.params.data or props.params.node.data nothing happens.

The fact that i declare my rowData using v-model but nothing happens makes me think I am missing something in the way I use my datas, but I don’t know what.

I thank you in advance to help me

I tried using setDataValue, setData and setRowData. Each times the cells are reset and i loose the focus on my component.

I was exepecting not a refresh of the components but just the props changing.

Comment: You've got quite a bit going on at once, and will be hard to get you full answer that nails everything... Have you looked into valueGetter? You can "compute" the value, and still have it be editable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ag-grid-vue (30.1) behaves differently than you would expect from a Vue component.

For starters, ag-grid-vue does not update the `params` prop after initialization. To make the component updateable, it has to expose a `refresh()` method. If it doesn't, any update will replace the whole component with a new instance, destroying your input element, which leads to a loss of focus.

From what I have seen, ag-grid-vue does not work well with a setup function, I would suggest using classic options API. So your component would look something like this:

```
export default {
  template: `<input :value="cellValue" @input="onInput"/>`,
  props: ['params'],
  expose: ['refresh'], // <---- expose refresh method
  data(){
    return {
      cellValue: null, // <---- local copy of cell value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      const fieldId = this.params.colDef.field
      const value = event.target.value
      this.params.node.setDataValue(fieldId, value) // <---- trigger cell update
    },
    refresh(newParams){
      this.cellValue = newParams.value  // <---- update local value
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.refresh(this.params) // <---- initial setup of local value
  },
}
```

Now the component sets a local value on initialization, and updates the value through the exposed `refresh()` method.

For the moment, managing the cell value manually seems to be the only option. In theory, the ag-grid-vue component supports a `autoParamsRefresh` prop, that sets a default `refresh()` method, which updates component props on update (search the [release notes](https://blog.ag-grid.com/introducing-version-20-of-ag-grid/) for a description). However, it does not seem to work with Vue 3, as it just tries to override the props, giving you a error as those are readonly: `Uncaught TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property '"params"'`.

---

If you try out the above, you'll find that it works, but only after the first edit. The first time you edit a value, the component is still replaced and focus is lost.

The problem is that `ref()` turns the array items into proxy objects, but ag-grid-vue returns the raw data. So when you use `v-model` to bind the rows, after the first update, the internal watcher compares the old proxy input and the new data values, and since they are different objects, ag-grid-vue concludes that the whole rows were changed and replaces the components.

Use `shallowRef` instead of `ref` to pass in data as ag-grid-vue expects it:

```html
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    v-model="rows"
    ...
  />
</template>
<script>

</script setup>
  import {shallowRef} from 'vue'
  const rows = shallowRef([...])
</script>
```

Now `rows` matches the format used by ag-grid-vue, avoiding the initial error.

---

Finally, you can combine first and last name to full name. I would use getters and setter for this:

```
{ 
  firstname: "John", 
  lastname: "Doe", 
  get fullname(){
    return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
  },
  set fullname(name){
    const [fn, ln] = name.split(' ')
    this.firstname = fn
    this.lastname = ln
  }
}
```

But there are other options as well. If you want to do it through ag-grid-vue, you have to use `setDataValue()` instead of `setData()`, as the latter will always re-initialize all components of the row.

---

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer, it seems to be promising ! I'll try it on Monday and give you a feedback.

Comment: Great, happy to hear it! Yes, let me know if it is working. The ag-grid-vue is quite idiosyncratic, I am curious what you'll find.

Comment: Indeed, `shallowRef` is the key factor in this answer; it should be in a TLDR at the top. In any case, IMHO I don't think there's an issue with Composition API (ie `<script setup>`).